# access msg.payload in uibuilder node-red - msg.payload in plotly is not working

Tags: javascript, node-red

In uibuilder in node-red I am trying to plot my `msg.payload` using `plotly` library. 
I am using `scope.$watch` to access my `msg.payload` inside my script but it does not work. I do not have any plot on my screen. Do I use the good method to access my `msg.payload` inside my `<script></script>` and then pass it to my `html` code ?

in my `getData()` function I should (would like) to get the msg.payload which is actually a value from a gauge cell. Then this value should be given into the chart to plot in real time the gauge cell values... Actually with my code, I do not get any value in my chart...

I have imported the plotly library above my code

```
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>


 <div class="navbar"><span>Real-Time Chart with Plotly.js</span></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <script>

            (function(scope) {
                scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {
                    getData(msg.payload);
            });

            function getData(d) {
                return d;
            }  
            Plotly.plot('chart',[{
                y:[getData()],
                type:'line'
            }]);

            var cnt = 0;
            setInterval(function(){
                Plotly.extendTraces('chart',{ y:[[getData()]]}, [0]);
                cnt++;
                if(cnt > 500) {
                    Plotly.relayout('chart',{
                        xaxis: {
                            range: [cnt-500,cnt]
                        }
                    });
                }
            },15);
            })(scope);
        </script>
```

Comment: It updated my post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Node-RED standard dashboard is built around Angular, which allows you to use scope.$watch. You mentioned in the OP that you are using ui-builder, which is a contrib node that replaces node-RED dashboard. As far as I know ui-builder does not use Angular (therefore scope.$watch is not supposed to work). I don´t use ui-builder so I may be wrong. I suggest posting this question in Node-RED forum to have a direct answer from ui-builder developer.